# macOS, user/group with no privileges to delete

Tags: macos, unix, acl

In my environment we use macs. I've been asked if it's possible to remove the capability of deleting files/folders for users. Most of our users are developers and we provide local admin rights to their accounts so that they can install apps and do some advanced stuff without much hassle. Now, I've been reading a bit about POSIX and ACLs but couldn't come up with a solution. If the user is a local admin, I don't think there's a way to limit its privileges. I imagine creating another type of user between admin and standard, basically a user that can still create files and folders (at least inside his home folder) and install apps but can't delete any files or folders. Is this something possible by any approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Without the ability to at least write some files a user probably can't even login (or at least not do anything meaningful). What exactly do you want to prevent from happening with these restrictions? Would it be possible to restrict deletion on specific directories?

Comment: I dont mind the user writing, I think that's necessary. It's a weird inquiry raised due to some audit purposes. We want functional users, just limited in terms of deletion of files and folders.

Comment: macOS and applications also write configs, settings and a lot of other stuff in the background on behalf of the user. And one method of doing so is deleting the old file and writing a new one. So IMHO restricting a user from deleting *anything* will fail. Restricing deletion of specific directories and their content is easily done with ACLs though.